# Getting current session id when session data is stored in the ci_Sessions table

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am using ion auth to handle my authorization to controllers and i am storing session data into the database. I can see the session info is being stored into the database.

I am logged in as admin and i need to update the current session data to show that another user is logged in,in short, i am trying to impersonate a user by updating session user id with a user id i know of.

```
$user = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();

echo "<pre>";
//print_r($res);
    echo 'Hello  '.$user->email;
echo "</pre>";

    $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $last_session = $this->db->get('ci_sessions')->row_array();

    print_r($last_session['data']);//prints current session data
```

The first echo gets the correct email of logged in user and also the correct session data. My question is, is the this line `print_r($last_session['data']);`

always going to get me my session data even if multiple users are logged in?.

Comment: logically, i guess it should give you your session, because your session is the last one to access the script.

Comment: add $this->load->library('session');

Comment: I already have that autoloaded,in the library and drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no. The session data always change every 5 mins (default) this is set in the config.php `$config['sess_time_to_update']`. This change only updates an existing session record (if exists) and create new record if doesn't. You can see how it is being handled in the Session.php located in the system/libraries/Session.php.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason why it won't work: The id in the ci_sessions table isn't a simple escalating integer, it's something like this: 5f53811d120de015d8189d72fcfb0a13242b382a. And ordering by the id will simply put into a random order. At most you could try ordering by 'timestamp' instead of id.

I'm not sure if the problem Jeffrey mentions occurs with ion_auth or not however.